# Why won't an iframe load in a Lightning component if it extends another Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, iframe

I am building a Lightning component that loads an iframe of an internal app. I've brought the component down to its minimum valuable component and I still have the problem.

The component with the iframe:

```
<aura:component
        implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
        extends="c:SimpleBase"
        description="SimpleIframeComponent">

    <iframe src="https://example.com/"
            width="100%"
            height="500px"
            frameBorder="0" />

</aura:component>
```

The base component:

```
<aura:component description="SimpleBase" extensible="true" abstract="true">
</aura:component>
```

So long as I do not extend `SimpleBase`, the `iframe` loads. But if I do extend `SimpleBase`, the iframe won't load.

There are no errors in the developer log (console). Also, watching the network in developer tools, the URL doesn't even load, so it appears the component doesn't render at all when it extends the base component.

Why won't an iframe load in a Lightning component if it extends another Lightning component?

Comment: did you check developer log in chrome for errors?

Comment: Yes, there are no errors in developer log. Note, there is no custom Javascript (no controller or helper).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `{!v.body}` in super component ***SimpleBase*** without which the body of sub-component will not load.

Reason: ([REFERENCE](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/salesforce-lightning-components-by-example-component-extension.html))

> sub component’s body is evaluated and passed to a super component to
>   use as {!v.body} and that super component’s body is evaluated and is
>   passed to its super component,